Error: Cannot find native module 'ExponentImagePicker', js engine: hermes
Trying to integrate "expo-image-picker" to a bare Expo project.
The problem comes from the following import.
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
The error is thrown from the requireNativeModule.js file.
I have tried all of the installations several times and I cannot get it to work.
Please help.

I'm seeing lots of questions asking "I'm getting an error 'Cannot find native module X, js engine: hermes". I have it for ExponentAV, part of expo-av. None of the suggestions - clearing out caches, deleting android folders, rebuilding with eas, or using npx expo run:android are fixing it.
I'm  guessing they broke something again, and eventually the noise will get so loud that they'll fix it.

I solved this by running a new development build.
eas build --profile development --platform <ios or android>
https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/
I guess a new development build needs to be run any time you install a new dependency to your project.

https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/use-development-builds/
True, whenever you add a library to your project that contains native code APIs, for example, expo-secure-store , you will have to rebuild the development.

You probably need do rebuild the project:
npx expo prebuild --clean
Then run using:
npx expo run:ios or npx expo run:android
You can find more info in the expo docs.

check if you have added the expo-image-picker to the plugins in your app.json
something like this:
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera to 
          let you ..."
        }
      ]
    ],

you also need to specify why you're asking for this permission for iOS.

In my case,

"Erase all content and settings" in the ios simulator

worked fine
